# Visual Studio Code Git Extension for branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-branch

I'm looking for a git extension in Visual Studio Code that can answer me these 2 questions:

Is my Branch already merged in other Branches?
Which Branches XYZ are merged in my Branch?

I tried a few extensions like GitHistory, GitLens etc. Maybe some extensions had this feature, and I have not seen it. Maybe any of you know if there's already a extension that can answer me exactly these 2 questions.

Thanks in forward,

Roadman :)

Comment: By "is branch in branch", do you mean "has branch X merged in my current branch"?

Comment: yep, that's correct. I changed the questions to be more specific.

Comment: To check if a branch is merged, I would open a Pull request (not sure what is the name of it in a VS extension - I prefer to use command line). If it has any differences, It wasn't merge.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Why not using `git branch --merged |grep [branch_name]` instead?

Comment: @ChatterOne because I didn't think about it :) - you are right, it is a simpler solution...